# Integrating Protobuf into Unreal Engine 4 (Linux)

Tags: linux, cmake, unreal-engine4, libc++

I'm having trouble integrating protobuf (3.20.4) into UE4 as a static library and packaging for linux.

The packaging fails with these errors :

```
undefined symbol: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::resize(unsigned long, char)
Error        PackagingResults     undefined symbol: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::reserve(unsigned long)
Error        PackagingResults     undefined symbol: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_append(char const*, unsigned long)
```

I'm assuming it's because I compiled them against libstdc++ rather than libc++ but I can't work out how to compile them using cmake with libc++.

Comment: I remember facing similar error, when using clang. basically protobuf was default built with gcc and rest of my application was built with clang. Basically libstdc++ vs libc++ made the difference,

Comment: So I tried to compile the protobuf libraries against the latest version of clang on my WSL terminal and include them in my unreal project. However I got this error :


`PackagingResults: Error: undefined symbol: google::protobuf::Message::CopyWithSourceCheck(google::protobuf::Message*, google::protobuf::Message const&)
PackagingResults: Error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

which I think is because I'm not using the version of clang & libc++ bundled with the engine.

Comment: It's hard to tell without complete build logs and linker command. As suggested above use `-v` for verbose linker output.